# eclipse mtj - proguard : obfuscate third party jar error

Tags: java, java-me, obfuscation, proguard, mtj

I use proguard (support in mtj plugin) to obfuscate a project that has some third party jars but it gives me errors:

```
 Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
 You may need to recompile them and try again.
 Alternatively, you may have to specify the options 
 '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses' and/or
 '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
```

It seems that proguard look for the classes in JavaSE not JavaME. It only happens with projects that use third party jars.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I saw is when I used third party API provided by OEMs like LG etc, I needed to set the proguard obfuscation level to 8 when compared to 9 which is the maximum level. Hope this wells.